# Windows Server 2008, Route LAN IP to choice of Gateway

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, routing, static-routes

On my windows server i have a WAN and LAN interface.

ON my LAN interface the ip is 10.200.0.1/16 and my WAN has an ip of 192.168.20.100 with multiple gateways192.168.20.1, 192.168.30.100, and 192.168.40.100

If i want to route the traffic of 10.200.0.8 to one of these Gateways how do i do so on the Windows Server 2008?

How can i choose to route any LAN IP i desire to a gateway on the WAN of which i choose?

What is the command or how do i setup this static route in the Routing and remote access section in windows server 2008?

Thanks!

Comment: `1.` AFAIK, you can't have multiple gateways. `2.` You can't have gateways on networks you're not directly connected to. `3.` What do you mean you want to route 10.200.0.8 traffic to one of the 192.x.x.x gateways?

Comment: Is there a way to essentially route traffic that is on a LAN IP to another gateway or IP on the WAN side? imagine like routing it through another interface. Same concept